# Old state is displayed when switching apps

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I press on the button to switch apps, the UI goes back to a previous state.

[image: current state]

[image: switching apps]

[image: old state]

The displayed time can go back by 0.5s up to 1s. Is there a way to prevent this?

I am using a loop that changes a flow which then updates the UI. (The refresh rate is 10ms. The same thing happened with a refresh rate of 100ms.)

```
    suspend fun refreshLoop() {
        while (true) {
            elapsedTimeFlow.value = elapsedTime
            delay(refreshRate)
        }
    }
```

```
    val formattedTime by viewModel.elapsedTimeFlow.collectAsState("")
```

```
        Text(text = formattedTime, fontSize = 100.sp, lineHeight = 100.sp)
```

Comment: what's `elapsedTime`, how do you calculate it? I'd says the correct way is storing start like `val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()` and calculating elapsed using `System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime`

Comment: @PhilDukhov I keep track of `startTime` and use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`: `(if (isRunning) (currentTime - startTime!!) else 0) + accumulatedTime}`